# Use function to create plot objects, then place them into figure

Tags: python, object, matplotlib, plot, subplot

So I've been working with an example like that shown in the [Usage Page](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles). The code for it is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n1 = 5
n2 = 30

x1 = np.linspace(0,10,n1)
y1 = np.random.rand(n1)
x2 = np.linspace(0,10,n2)
y2 = np.random.rand(n2)

#Matplotlib example copy paste
def my_plotter(ax, data1, data2, param_dict):
    out = ax.plot(data1, data2, **param_dict)
    return out

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
my_plotter(ax1, x1, y1, {'marker':'x'})
my_plotter(ax2, x2, y2, {'marker':'o'})

plt.show()
```

Note that the docstring from the example has been deleted for space savings.

Issue is that if I get rid of the `param_dict` argument,

```
my_plotter(ax1, x1, y1)
my_plotter(ax2, x2, y2)
```

, not only does it not work (nothing is displayed upon running the script and running plt.show() in the console after the script has run brings up blank subplots), but not a single error is raised. If I run only the first instance of `my_plotter`, the figure will display, the first subplot will plot `x1` and `y1`, and the second will be blank; exactly what I would be expecting. Snooping around, I found a similar format of code:

```
def axtest(x, y, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    ret = ax.plot(x, y)
    return(ret)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
print('blah')
axtest(x1, y1, ax1)
axtext(x2, y2, ax2)

plt.show()
```

This code shows the same exact behavior as the functions above; one instance of `axtest` will plot a non-blank and blank subplot and two instances of `axtest` will do nothing, no errors to speak of.

What am I missing? Do I have to pass parameters to the axes to get this to work? Because that makes no sense to me.

My end goal in this is to take some code I have that does this:

```
def orig_func(x, y, z):
   X, Y, Z = interpolate_to_grid(x, y, z)
   fig = plt.figure()
   plt.imshow(Z)
   plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
   plt.scatter(X, Y, c=Z)
   #do formating of the data
   plt.show()
```

and make it do this:

```
def new_func(x, y, z):
   X, Y, Z = interpolate_to_grid(x, y, z)
   fig = plt.figure()
   plt.imshow(Z)
   plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
   plt.scatter(X, Y, c=Z)
   #do formating of the data
   return(the plot info)

plot_info1 = new_func(x1, y1, z1)
plot_info2 = new_func(x2, y2, z2)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax1 = plot_info1
ax2 = plot_info2

plt.show()
```

I thought this wouldn't be that difficult, but hey, shows you what I know. Any help would be quite nice.

Comment: Your function should take in `Axes` objects as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you didn't have a small mistake in your first attempt.  The following works fine for me.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n1 = 5
n2 = 30

x1 = np.linspace(0,10,n1)
y1 = np.random.rand(n1)
x2 = np.linspace(0,10,n2)
y2 = np.random.rand(n2)

#Matplotlib example copy paste
def my_plotter(ax, data1, data2):
    out = ax.plot(data1, data2)
    return out

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
my_plotter(ax1, x1, y1)
my_plotter(ax2, x2, y2)

plt.show()
```

So the question left is what is wrong with your second example.  In the example listed above, we have a function which is given an axis object (ax) as well as the data.  It returns that very same axis object which now has plotting on it.

You had a figure being created within the function, but that is not needed since we already have the figure created here

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
```

and then we markup that first ax1 with

```
my_plotter(ax1, x1, y1)
```

and then markup that second ax2 with

```
my_plotter(ax2, x2, y2)
```

And finally make sure that your function is altering the axis object.  Before, you had ax.plot().  You changed to plt.scatter.  Try ax.scatter() instead.

Comment: Ok, now we're getting into weird stuff. I copy pasted, that script into a seperate script and it did work. What I doing originally was not editing the function at all (ie, keep `def my_plotter(ax, data1, data2, param_dict`). Is there a way to keep the option of the parameter dictionary available?

Comment: Also, the next question then is what is wrong with the second example (`def axtest`)? They look practically identical except for a few things that shouldn't happen.

Comment: you can always add back in the parameters, and just pass an empty mapping when using the function.  my_plotter(ax1, x1, y1,{})

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Annoying, but it works, so not too much to complain about.